# How do screenshot in c# (low level may be) when desktop blocked?

Tags: c#, screenshot

I try get screenshot (windows 8) with code and get black screen when desktop blocked:

```
    public static Bitmap ImageFromScreen()
    {
        Graphics gr;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        gr.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
            0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: may be use directx , but third library (for ex. using SlimDX.Direct3D9;) not good

Comment: Do you mean when the desktop is *locked*?

Comment: When press Ctrl+Alt+Del desktop lock capture

Comment: Could you perhaps call a "show desktop" internal before calling CopyFromScreen? - this will cause a flickr obviously

Comment: Why are you trying to take a screenshot of the desktop when it's locked? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

Apart from window cache (which isn't accessible, and doesn't really have to be there), the data simply isn't there. You'd have to fake WM_PAINT messages and force the application to draw to your surface (most controls will take the HDC from `wParam`; that still excludes a ton of badly written (or not Windows-native) applications - and even then, this will not work most of the time, like when the windows are minimized or the desktop is locked.

<strike>What is it that you're *actually* trying to do?</strike>

**EDIT:**

Okay, it's obvious that you're explicitly talking about the "locked screen" case - there's no way to get a screenshot of the desktop in that case - it doesn't *really* exist. The lock screen exists in a different session, so you no longer have any connection to the "hidden" user session. This is similar to trying to take screenshots on a server application after you've disconnected Remote Desktop - there's nothing to take shots of. It may be possible to force *some* applications to draw to your context, but nothing that would simply work.